# Is it possible to model operation parameters as vararg in Eclipse/EMF?

Tags: java, eclipse, emf, eclipse-emf

I'm trying to find a way to model an operation with a vararg input parameter.

The model should generate an interface as shown below.

```
/**
 * ...
 * @generated
 */
public interface Content extends EObject {
    /**
     * ...
     * @generated
     */
    List<Definition> getDefinitionsByLabels(String... label);      


}
```

Please don't answer with workarounds because I'm trying to update a model of an existing (large) code base (that was "manually" developed further post generation).

So far investigating this didn't look promising, but I didn't want to give up on this aspect without asking a question here.

[image: Example Class Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since varargs is not supported directly by the code generator of EMF, someone asked to make the upper limit a marker for varargs.
The bug report is pending, i.e. the requested feature is not available:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337052

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a var-arg **Java method** on your model class, and you **don't need a proper EMF operation**, then this is possible to solve:

Make your model class implement a Java interface, where the vararg method is declared.

Java file:

```
public interface InterfaceWithVarargMethod {
    public void varArgMethod(String... arg);
}
```

Xcore file:

```
@GenModel(modelDirectory="/EMF_Trying/src-gen")
package emf_trying

interface InterfaceWithVarargMethod wraps InterfaceWithVarargMethod {}

class ModelObject extends InterfaceWithVarargMethod {
}
```

An implementation of `ModelObjectImpl` without the var-arg method will get generated. You have to edit the generated code and add the var-arg method for the code to compile:

```
public class ModelObjectImpl extends MinimalEObjectImpl.Container implements ModelObject {
    /**
     * @generated NOT
     */
    @Override
    public void m(String... arg) {
        // Implementation of var-arg method
    }

    ...
}
```

Maybe it is possible to find some variation of this solution where you don't have to edit the generated code. For example by adding a default implementation of the method in the interface, then overriding the method in a hand-written subclass to the EClass.